# Primefaces slider won't reset to 0

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, slider

I have a JSF form with a Slider and a reset button :

```
<div class="field">
    <p:outputLabel for="amount" value="Amount" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom: 10px" id="amount">
        <p:inputText id="slider" value="#{myBean.myBo.amount}" />
        <p:slider for="slider" maxValue="20" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</div>

<h:commandButton value="Reset" type="reset" action="#{myBean.reset}" update="form" process="@this" class="button"></h:commandButton>
```

The reset function looks like this :

```
public void reset() {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("form:form");
    this.registrationFormBo.clear();
}
```

when resetting the slider its output looks like this :
[image]

The `p:inputText` has the correct value while the slider itself has the value 9 in this example.

**Problem**

The slider does not reset while the value does.

Comment: Try to use process="@form"

Comment: @MarcelJacquesMachado this does not work

Comment: OK. So why are you using "form:form"?

Comment: I think I didn't understand the selector, I changed it to `:registrationForm`. but I don't think I need the reset function. can't I just use this button : `<h:commandButton value="Reset" type="reset" process="@form" class="button"></h:commandButton>`. This doen't solve the slider problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I solved This problem by using Primefaces `p:resetInput`. The final html of the reset button looks like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Reset" update="registrationForm" process="@this" >
    <p:resetInput target="registrationForm" />
</p:commandButton>
```

This resets the slider and every other element in the form correctly.